# Mavericks on MacBook early 2008

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, display, audio

I have recently installed Mavericks on my MacBook early 2008 (which doesn't support mavericks) but I have two problems. The first problem is that I can't change the brightness of the screen. When I try to change the brightness it doesn't change. The second problem is that the speakers don't work. I have tried a lot of things but nothing works. Is there someone who know what is should do?

Answer (score 1):

impossible.
the max for that macbook is Lion 10.7.5